# Get data based on condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My table

```
loads(Unique)       Value
 T123                11
 T234               9.5
 T456               15
 T678               35
 T345               3.7
```

Want I want

```
 count(values<=10)    count(values>10 &<=20)   count(values>20) 
            2                       2                    1
```

I tried to use CASE but don't know the usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` yes; not with `COUNT` but with `SUM`:

```
SQL> with test (loads, value) as
  2    (select 't123', 11   from dual union all
  3     select 't234',  9.5 from dual union all
  4     select 't456', 15   from dual union all
  5     select 't678', 35   from dual union all
  6     select 't345',  3.7 from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    sum(case when value <= 10 then 1 end) cnt_1,
 10    sum(case when value > 10  and value <= 20 then 1 end) cnt_2,
 11    sum(case when value > 20 then 1 end) cnt_3
 12  from test;

     CNT_1      CNT_2      CNT_3
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation as

```
select coalesce(sum(case when value<=10 then 1 end),0) as "values<=10",
       coalesce(sum(case when value>10 and value<=20 then 1 end),0) as "values>10value<20",
       coalesce(sum(case when value>20 then 1 end),0) as "values>20"
from your_table;
```